# Apache Directory Listing Trims filenames

Tags: apache-2.2

Apache is trimming the filenames when using the directory listing feature.

How can I change the trimming length (or disable it)?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IndexOptions FancyIndexing NameWidth=*`
should interrest you

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#IndexOptions

Comment: exactly what I was looking for..., it worked perfectly. Thanks!